# Unable to IK rig this simple mech

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I made this simple lego mech but when I try to IK rig it, the bones are always deformed and I can never adjust to a standard T pose. I tried following the royal skies tutorial but I could never get it to work once I set the foot IK as the target. I am relatively new to blender and would like to understand why this is happening and if someone could explain how to correctly set the limit rotations to avoid any clipping.

https://easyupload.io/nzp4an

Comment: What version of Blender did you use to create that file?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: It's a compressed blend file 3.0, and not supported by 2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what you're saying from looking at the file.  There is no bone called "foot IK".  And if I look at the armature and model, I would describe this as already being in a T-pose.  (If you want to rotate SHOULDER.L to make a T-pose, the reason it won't rotate is because you have restricted the axis in which you'd want it to rotate, its local Z axis, via a Limit Rotation constraint.)

If you were trying to set "FOOT.L" as the IK target of "SHIN.L", the reason that doesn't work is because FOOT.L is parented to SHIN.L.  The parenting means that foot depends on shin.  But if shin has an IK constraint, then shin depends on foot.  Which depends on shin, which depends on foot.  I think you can see the problem.

If we want IK controls for the legs, here's what we should do:

1. In edit mode, duplicate FOOT.L (to "FOOT.L.001") and unparent this new bone.
2. In pose mode, designate FOOT.L.001 as the IK target for the existing IK constraint on SHIN.L.  (Which is already set to a chain length of 2.)

Now we can test it, by moving FOOT.L.001 around.  We'll see the leg tracks our new target just fine:

[image]

I've also selected SHIN.L in that screenshot so you could see the settings yourself.

Blender's IK will bend the leg in the direction of its existing (rest pose) bend, and only in that direction.  If that's not the direction you want, you can rotate SHIN.L in pose mode to change the bend (and see how the IK responds.)

If you would instead like to use a pole target, I'd recommend the following:

1. Enable the display of axes for your armature, in properties/object/viewport display, so that you can see what you're doing.
2. Change your orientation, at the top of your screen, from "Global" to "Normal".
3. In edit mode, duplicate THIGH.L (to THIGH.L.001) and move it constrained to its x axis, in the direction that its x axis is pointing.  Because you're in normal orientation, you can do this by hitting 'g' then 'x' then '20' then enter, to move it 20 units in the direction of its X axis.  Then unparent your new bone.
4. In pose mode, designate your new bone as the pole target for your IK constraint.

You now have a pole target that will control the rotation of the leg-- in particular, it will be same at rest as constrained, and your thigh's X axis will always point at it, wherever you move it:

[image]

"How to correctly set the limit rotations to avoid any clipping"?

Basically, the answer is, you don't.  Trying to control clipping via constraints on any object that is more complicated than a cube or a sphere is a losing battle.  You rely on the animator (you, probably) to not pose it that way.  It's like the old joke:

> Patient: "It hurts when I raise my arm."
>
> Doctor, "Then don't raise your arm."

I know, it's not a very funny joke.

You can create angle limits for your bones in a number of different ways, but none of those ways are going to have anything to do with your mesh: they are either going to be overly restrictive, or else there will be poses in which clipping is still possible.

There are multiple ways to control angles.  The ones most relevant to you right now are:

1. IK angle limits.  These can be specified, with a bone that is part of an IK chain selected in pose mode, in properties/bone/IK.  But they should be avoided; used poorly, the will cause IK twitch-- poor interpolations between poses that seem like they should be fine.

[image]

2. Limit Rotation constraints.  These will not work on bones controlled by IK, like your shin and thigh. And they are unlikely to work as new riggers anticipate, because 3D angles are not really 3 independent angles as first intuited, but are actually dependent on each other, and depend on which order you read the axes.

It looks like you've already started using Limit Rotation constraints, and you haven't mentioned any particular problem with them, so I'm assuming that you know about them already.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you for taking the time to clearly explain this to me. I have applied this to my model and everything works beautifully! I understand everything very clearly know and have a much better grasp on IK rigging. will keep this in mind when working on my future projects!